# Show div upon tabbing into a certain input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a date picker when the user gets to a certain input on a form. The datepicker should display if the user simply tabs into the field.

I tried something like this (I'm using [Zebra_DatePicker](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/) by the way):

```
var datepicker = $('#date-picker-input').data('Zebra_DatePicker')
$('#date-picker-input').focus(function(){
    datepicker.show()
})
```

That works - tabbing into the field shows the datepicker. However, this breaks the functionality if the user decides to click on the input field in question; when this happens, the click initially opens the datepicker, and then the focus callback function closes it. The result is a split-second flicker where the datepicker is shown then closes instantly.

How can I get functionality for both clickers and tabbers?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zebra DatePicker, but try just doing: `$('#date-picker-input').focus(...);`.  Why are you grabbing the `data` value?

Comment: Maybe look into using preventDefault(), then set a focus AND a click event to the datepicker.

Comment: @Madbreaks Edited above; doesn't fix the issue. Using the `data` function gives the `show` method to the datepicker.

Comment: @CrazyPaste I think you're onto something, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `data('Zebra_DatePicker')` returns a reference to the date-picker component and not to the element itself so your `focus` event binding is performed on the wrong object.

Try this:

```
$('#date-picker-input').on('focus click', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).data('Zebra_DatePicker').show();
})
```

Comment: Edited above to use `$('#date-picker-input')`. Same problem - clicking on that element causes a click AND a focus, resulting in an open-close situation.

Comment: That works, but it appears to cause an OPEN-CLOSE-OPEN situation instead of an OPEN-CLOSE. Functionally it works, but there's a noticeable flicker as it opens, closes, and opens.

Comment: Still seeing the OPEN-CLOSE-OPEN flicker.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin does not support what you are asking nor does it offer many hooks, so the workaround will be a bit hacky..

If you are working with a single datepicker in the page do

on initialization of plugin

```
$('#date-picker-input').Zebra_DatePicker({
  // what options you already use
  // and then add
  onSelect: function () {
      var datepicker = $(this).data('Zebra_DatePicker');
      setTimeout(function () {
        datepicker.hide();
      }, 1);
    }
});
```

and then add

```
$('#date-picker-input').off('click').on('focus', function(){
  var datepicker = $(this).data('Zebra_DatePicker');

  datepicker.show();
  return false;
});
```